# Unable to parse xml data with address in Account object with address field

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, xml, package.xml

My requirement I have XML data with a set address I need to insert all XML address data into the Account object with the Address field respectively. any solution to this.

My updated  code:
If I insert and debug am getting this on debug page:
[image]

```
   public class Xmldata {
  
 public static void parseContactAddress() {
  String s = 
'<Content '+
    'xmlns="urn:crif-CrifGate:2:1">'+
    '<CES_ServiceOutput>'+
        '<CCR_Output>'+
       '<id type="integer">7</id>'+
        '<CG_CCR_Pipe>'+
      ' <id type="integer">7</id>'+
    '<CB_NAE_ProductOutput '+
'xmlns:cb="urn:crif-creditbureau:v1"> <address>'+
      '<name>Kirk Stevens</name>'+
      '<street1>808 State St</street1>'+
      '<street2>Apt. 2</street2>'+
      '<city>Palookaville</city>'+
      '<state>PA</state>'+
      '<country>USA</country>'+
  '</address>'+ 
   '</CB_NAE_ProductOutput>'+
            '</CG_CCR_Pipe>'+
        '</CCR_Output>'+
         '</CES_ServiceOutput>'+
            
'</Content>';
 
    
List<Account> newaccounts = new List<Account> ();

Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
docx.load(s);
dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getrootelement() ;

dom.XmlNode [] xrec = xroot.getchildelements() ; //Get all Record Elements

for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec) //Loop Through Records
{
 account a = new Account ();

  for (dom.XmlNode awr : child.getchildren() ) {
                         if(awr.getName() == 'CG_CCR_Pipe') {
    for(Dom.XmlNode CG_CCR_Pipe: awr.getChildren()) {
            if (awr.getname() == 'id') {
                               system.debug('Id' + awr.gettext());
                a.accountnumber = awr.gettext();
        if(CG_CCR_Pipe.getName() == 'CB_NAE_ProductOutput') {
            for(Dom.XmlNode productOutputChild: CG_CCR_Pipe.getChildren()) {
                if(productOutputChild.getName() == 'address') {
                    for(Dom.XmlNode addressChild: productOutputChild.getChildren()) {
                        String childText = addressChild.getText();
                        switch on addressChild.getName() {
                            
                            when 'name' {
                                a.Name = childText;
                            }
                            when 'street1' {
                                a.BillingStreet = childText;
                            }
                            when 'street2' {
                                a.BillingStreet = child.getText().trim();
                            }
                            when 'city' {
                                a.BillingCity = childText;
                            }
                            when 'state' {
                                a.BillingState= childText;
                            }
                            when 'country' {
                                a.BillingCountry = childText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
  }
  }
 
   insert newaccounts;

}
system.debug(newaccounts);//you could insert here or upsert based on ID with an external Id field
 }
        
}
```

Please help..

Need this ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to figure out each child element to get to the address. This means you'll need a deeply nested if/for statement.

**Previously Noted Code Reacted**

Here's a working version:

```
public class Xmldata {
    
    public static void parseContactAddress() {
        String s = 
            '<Content '+
            'xmlns="urn:crif-CrifGate:2:1">'+
            '<CES_ServiceOutput>'+
            '<CCR_Output>'+
            '<id type="integer">7</id>'+
            '<CG_CCR_Pipe>'+
            ' <id type="integer">7</id>'+
            '<CB_NAE_ProductOutput '+
            'xmlns:cb="urn:crif-creditbureau:v1"> <address>'+
            '<name>Kirk Stevens</name>'+
            '<street1>808 State St</street1>'+
            '<street2>Apt. 2</street2>'+
            '<city>Palookaville</city>'+
            '<state>PA</state>'+
            '<country>USA</country>'+
            '</address>'+ 
            '</CB_NAE_ProductOutput>'+
            '</CG_CCR_Pipe>'+
            '</CCR_Output>'+
            '</CES_ServiceOutput>'+
            
            '</Content>';
        
        
        List<Account> newaccounts = new List<Account> ();
        
        Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        docx.load(s);
        dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getrootelement() ;
        
        dom.XmlNode [] xrec = xroot.getchildelements() ; //Get all Record Elements
        
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : xrec) //Loop Through Records
        {
            for (dom.XmlNode awr : child.getchildren() ) {
                if(awr.getName() == 'CCR_Output') {
                    account a = new Account ();
                    for(Dom.XmlNode CCR_Output: awr.getChildren()) {
                        if (CCR_Output.getname() == 'id') {
                            a.accountnumber = awr.gettext();
                        }
                        if(CCR_Output.getName() == 'CG_CCR_Pipe') {
                            for(Dom.XmlNode ccrPipeChild: CCR_Output.getChildren()) {
                                if(ccrPipeChild.getName() == 'CB_NAE_ProductOutput') {
                                    for(Dom.XmlNode productOutputChild: ccrPipeChild.getChildren()) {
                                        if(productOutputChild.getName() == 'address') {
                                            for(Dom.XmlNode addressChild: productOutputChild.getChildren()){
                                                String childText = addressChild.getText();
                                                switch on addressChild.getName() {
                                                    when 'name' {
                                                        a.Name = childText;
                                                    }
                                                    when 'street1' {
                                                        a.BillingStreet = childText;
                                                    }
                                                    when 'street2' {
                                                        a.BillingStreet += child.getText();
                                                    }
                                                    when 'city' {
                                                        a.BillingCity = childText;
                                                    }
                                                    when 'state' {
                                                        a.BillingState= childText;
                                                    }
                                                    when 'country' {
                                                        a.BillingCountry = childText;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    newaccounts.add(a);
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug(newaccounts);//you could insert here or upsert based on ID with an external Id field
        insert newaccounts;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: still am unable to insert the address data in the account address field, if I debug nothing is inserted, the full bank can you please help.

Comment: can you give any suggestion on it. regarding this code

Comment: @Meenurosy Did you actually insert the data? There's no `insert newaccounts;` in your code.

Comment: yes I have inserted and debugged am unable to insert the address data in the Account objects with the Address field, I have an update of the code, can you look over it?

Comment: Need to pass the record id of account and insert the XML address data in Address filed in Account object @sfdcfox

Comment: Can you please help out ,i have inserted the insert `newaccounts;` but in account object Address field doesn't updated with XML data...can you please help @sfdcfox

Comment: hi I can you help out to resolve please

Comment: @Meenurosy I fixed the new code... you had missed a number of elements. I'm concerned you won't learn much from this, though. The point is that you need to parse each child node in order.